# How to fixed number digit limit in input tag using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In html input tah, when I set max="16", it can take more than 16. Like, if I enter more than 16 digit, it allows me to enter. But I wanted that, Only 16 digit can enter, not Number 16. Not more than.

How can I do it.....?

Comment: The `max` property isnt length, its the value. `15` would be correct, `17` invalid

Answer (score -1):

You can use max="" attribute.

Example:   `<input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="16">`

Comment: @Md. Ibrahim, I've used it. But not working. If I type more than 16 digit, it Works..

Comment: Sorry @DavidThomas.. Typing Mistakes.